# Calculus (first year) challenging arcsin integration

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm currently studying for a midterm, and this question has me stumped:

> Given that $\int_0^1(\arcsin x)^6,dx = k$, find the value of $\int_0^1(\arcsin x)^8,dx$ in terms of k. Simplify your final answer as much as possible.

I'm at a loss how to approach this, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Usually reduction formulas are the result of integration by parts.  Have you tried that?

Comment: I did, but it`s incredibly long which doesn`t really feel feasible for a midterm. I figure there might be something more efficient I`m missing.

Comment: Can you post your result? Maybe we can help you simplify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integration by parts is the way to go. You should be able to get a nice, clean result in two iterations. For your first iteration let $u =\arcsin(x)^8$ and $dv = 1$. This should lead you to $$\int_0^1\arcsin(x)^8\text{d}x =  \space x\arcsin(x)^8\bigg\vert_0^1-\int_0^1\frac{8\arcsin(x)^7}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\text{d}x $$ With a choice substitution on your second iteration, you should be able to find $$\int_0^1 \arcsin(x)^8\text{d}x = \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^8-56k$$ But I will let you fill in the details.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much! I never thought of letting dv = 1

Comment: @Matthew happy to help! It's a nice trick for integration by parts. I first learned it when solving $\int \ln(x)\text{d}x$